# How to fill dates in between in subquery?

Tags: clickhouse

I have got a table with purchases:

```
player_id | date       | registration_date | price
   pl1    | 2019-01-21 | 2019-01-20        |  20
   pl1    | 2019-01-23 | 2019-01-20        |  10
   pl1    | 2019-01-24 | 2019-01-20        |  15
```

After calculations with groupArray on 'date' and arrayCumSum on 'price' and using ArrayJoin I got the table with cumulative sum on each day:

```
player_id | date       | registration_date | sum_price
   pl1    | 2019-01-21 | 2019-01-20        |  20
   pl1    | 2019-01-23 | 2019-01-20        |  30
   pl1    | 2019-01-24 | 2019-01-20        |  45
```

But I need to add missing dates since registration until today (today is `'2019-01-25'`):

```
player_id | date       | registration_date | sum_price
   pl1    | 2019-01-20 | 2019-01-20        |  0
   pl1    | 2019-01-21 | 2019-01-20        |  20
   pl1    | 2019-01-22 | 2019-01-20        |  20
   pl1    | 2019-01-23 | 2019-01-20        |  30
   pl1    | 2019-01-24 | 2019-01-20        |  45
   pl1    | 2019-01-25 | 2019-01-20        |  45
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Can you also provide your query?

Comment: There is no need to ask if you know how to do it

Comment: Good luck with finding answers here :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```sql
SELECT player_id, result.1 as date, registrationDate as registration_date, result.2 as sum_price
FROM
(
    SELECT
        player_id,
        groupArray((date, price)) AS purchases,
        min(registration_date) AS registrationDate,
        arrayMap(x -> registrationDate + x, range(toUInt32(toDate('2019-01-25') - registrationDate + 1))) dates,
        arrayFilter(x -> arrayFirstIndex(p -> p.1 = x, purchases) = 0, dates) AS missed_dates,
        arrayMap(x -> (x, 0), missed_dates) AS dummy_purchases,
        arraySort(x -> x.1, arrayConcat(purchases, dummy_purchases)) all_purchases,
        arrayCumSum(x -> x.2, all_purchases) cum_prices,
        arrayMap(index -> (all_purchases[index].1, cum_prices[index]), arrayEnumerate(all_purchases)) flat_result,
        arrayJoin(flat_result) result
    FROM test.purchases01
    GROUP BY player_id
)

/* result
┌─player_id─┬───────date─┬─registration_date─┬─sum_price─┐
│ pl1       │ 2019-01-20 │        2019-01-20 │         0 │
│ pl1       │ 2019-01-21 │        2019-01-20 │        20 │
│ pl1       │ 2019-01-22 │        2019-01-20 │        20 │
│ pl1       │ 2019-01-23 │        2019-01-20 │        30 │
│ pl1       │ 2019-01-24 │        2019-01-20 │        45 │
│ pl1       │ 2019-01-25 │        2019-01-20 │        45 │
└───────────┴────────────┴───────────────────┴───────────┘

*/


/* Prepare test data */

CREATE TABLE test.purchases01
(
    `player_id` String,
    `date` Date,
    `registration_date` Date,
    `price` int
)
ENGINE = Memory;

INSERT INTO test.purchases01
VALUES  ('pl1', '2019-01-21', '2019-01-20', 20), 
        ('pl1', '2019-01-23', '2019-01-20', 10), 
        ('pl1', '2019-01-24', '2019-01-20', 15);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I noticed that you are a great expert in questions about Clickhouse. Can you recommend me any specific literature or online course because the official guide does not answer my questions all the time?

Comment: @Jens I would recommend looking at [official documents](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/query_language/functions/higher_order_functions), [meetups/confs](https://www.youtube.com/c/ClickHouseDB) , [meetup/confs materials](https://github.com/yandex/clickhouse-presentations).